# Possible to use a BRIN Index on a Primary Key in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, primary-key

I was reading up on the BRIN index within PostgreSQL, and it seems to be beneficial to many of the tables we use.

That said, it applies nicely to a column which is already the primary key, in which case adding a separate index would negate *part* of the benefit of the index, which is space savings.

A PK is implicitly indexed, is it not?  On that note, can it be done using a BRIN instead of a Btree, assuming the Btree is also implicit?

I tried this, and as expected it did not work:

```
create table foo (
  id integer,
  constraint foo_pk primary key using BRIN (id)
)
```

So, two questions:

1. Can a BRIN index be used on a PK?
2. If not, will the planner pick the more appropriate of the two if I have both a PK and a separate BRIN index (if performance means more to me than space)

And it's course possible that my understanding of this is incomplete, in which case I would appreciate any enlightenment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Primary keys are a logical combination of NOT NULL and UNIQUE, therefore only an index type that supports uniqueness can be used.

From the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) (currently version 13):

> Only B-tree currently supports unique indexes.

2. I'm not so sure BRIN would be faster than B-tree. [It's a lot more space-efficient, but the fact that it's lossy and requires a secondary verification pass erodes any potential speed advantages.](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/07/16/brin-index-for-postgresql-dont-forget-the-benefits/) Once you are locked into having your B-tree primary key index, there's not much point to making a secondary overlapping BRIN index.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: Is it possible to implement BRIN index in addition to PKEY to improve queries speed, but also to preserve the ability to protect INSERTs from pushing non-unique values?